# Get input type array value with key in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

```
<input type='number' name="productId" id="productId" value="5">
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity">
```

To get my quantity value I used

```
 var values = $("input[name='quantity[]']")
            .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

It works fine to get my desired value. Now I want to use `productId` as my key and quantity values as a number.It has a submit button.Each time i will input productID and quantity it will push array values. I want to store these into a new array that looks like

```
var array = {
     2:10,
     3:5
};
```

Comment: In your markup, how do you determine which quantity is for which productId?

Comment: Do you have a submit button for this form? How does each productID get mapped to quantity? Is it on submit or onblur?

Comment: it has submit button.Each time when i input productId and Quantity it will push its value

Comment: Your "array" is actually an object literal. If it's this you want to use you won't be using push to add the values instead using dynamic key creation with square brackets []; like this -> `objectLiteral["myKey"] = myValue`

Comment: So there's one productId field and one quantity field which are re-used each time?

Comment: yes it is @Mark Walters

Answer (score 0):

```js
var products = [];
function addValue(){  
  var productId = $('#productId').val();
  var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
  var prod = {};
  
  if(products.filter(p=>p[productId]).length > 0){ 
      alert('The id ' + productId + ' is already included');
      return false;
  }

  prod[productId] = quantity; 
  products.push(prod);
  
  console.log(products);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type='number' name="productId" id="productId" value="5">
  <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="10">
  <button onclick="return addValue()">Add value</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = () => defineLogic();
let obj = {};
defineLogic = () => {
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = () => createArray(obj)
}

createArray = () => {
 const productId = document.getElementById("productId").value;
 const quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
 obj[productId] = quantity;
 console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

```html
<input type='number' name="productId" id="productId" value="5">
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity">
<button id="submit">Submit button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a selector to get the inputs. If you can be sure they're in the right order in the document and in pairs, then:

```js
function getResults() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  return {[inputs[0].value] : inputs[1].value};
};
```

```html
<input type='number' name="productId" id="productId" value="5">
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="2">
<br>
<button onclick="console.log(getResults())">Get results</button>
```

Can easily be adapted to create an object from any number of pairs.